# PHP/MYSQL: check if variable is empty

Tags: php, mysql, isset

I want to prevent an empty value from going into a MySQL database

I'm using following but for some reason it is letting the empty values get through...

```
if (trim($var)= '' || !isset($var)){
header("Location:page.php?er=novariablel");
}
else {
...insert into database
}
```

Note, there is a bunch of complicated stuff that sets the value of var which is why I want to have both the `=''` and the `!isset` because either might be the case.

Am I missing something with the or statement, i.e. it evaluates to false if both are true.  Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if (!isset($var) || empty(trim($var))){
```

[`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is a better way to check to see if a variable has no value. Just keep in mind that the following will return true:

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Answer (score 5):

You're lacking an `=` for your [Equal Comparison Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) inside your `if` statement. Try:

```
if (trim($var) == '' || !isset($var)){
```

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind to use `==` or `===` equality operators inside your conditional statements in future, otherwise you'll run in the same problem again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$var = trim($var);
if (!empty($var)){
  //not empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (strlen(trim($var)))==0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also have put a constraint in your database table attribute that it will not accept NULL values. Then your entry would have not been made in the database.

Answer (score 0):

@John this is great advice.

```
empty(trim($var))
```

I've been programming for 6 years and I never thought of trimming the variable before checking to see if it's empty.